Getting error "Unable to parse package2-descriptor.json: invalid attribute 'subscriberPackageId" using "release":"previous" in current preview window
I'm encountering an error today (2024-06-10) that I think I need Salesforce's assistance with.
I am trying to create a new beta package using sf-cli 2gp package creation.
Today when I create a package, it has begun to create packages against API version 61.0.  However to be backwards compatible with some dev orgs that are on 60.0, I've added "release":"previous", to the project-scratch-def.json.
Once this is added however, beta package creation fails with this error message.
Error (1): Multiple errors occurred: 
(1) Unable to parse package2-descriptor.json: invalid attribute 'subscriberPackageId' at line 1, column 345

From what I understand, this is the tooling API file in the underlying package creation code.  I do need to keep this setting in project-scratch-def.json, because if this beta code pans out, I'll need to create a new release package, and I'd rather not wait for the customer orgs to be upgraded before I install this new package.
Anyone else seeing this?

Did you, perchance, accidentally include any 61.0 versioned metadata in your package? It's easy enough to do by accident, and this might be the underlying cause of the behavior.

Great suggestion. I was hoping this was the case, however, I did a search for 61.0 in the project, but nothing was found.  Thanks for your suggestion.

in case anyone else is having similar issues, I was directed to this link. https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/2912. Status of this problem should show up there.

It was never resolved, but since the release window expired, this is just not an issue anymore.  Hopefully it doesn't rear it's head again next release.
